# How to use streams instead of loop to iterate jsonarray?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have done with **for loop** but i want do loop with the help of **stream and filter** like `Streams.stream(jsonArray).filter(....)`.

Below is my code :

```
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Values");
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
  JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
  if (jsonObj.getString("code").equalsIgnoreCase("sale")) {
    if ("1".equals(jsonObj.getString("value"))) {
      logger.info("Found");
    } else {
      logger.info("Not Found!");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Something like .... `...stream(jsonArray).filter(jsonObj -> jsonObj.getString("code").equalsIgnoreCase("sale")).forEach(jsonObj -> {if ("1".equals(jsonObj.getString("value"))) {
      logger.info("Found");
    } else {
      logger.info("Not Found!");
    }});`.. But what you've shared doesn't really look like a practical use case.

Comment: @LutzHorn i have imported ***org.json.JSONArray***

Comment: @LutzHorn Depends on the JSONArray being used. Might be `StreamSupport.stream(jsonArray.spliterator(), false)` or `jsonArray.stream()` in ittself. I wanted to just share the approach which I believe the question was for.

Answer (score 0):

Since `org.json.JSONArray` implements `Iterable<Object>`, you can use

```java
Stream<Object> stream = StreamStreamSupport.stream(a.spliterator(), false);
```

to get a stream from it. Then you can use the usual stream operations on this.